# How can I call a C++ function from C#?

Tags: c#, c++

How can I call a C++ function from C# .NET?

Answer (score 6):

1. compile the C++ function into a dll and [use P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

   or
2. compile the C++ function into a C++/CLI assembly, wrap in a managed C++ class, and then treat like any other assembly (add a reference, use a using statement and call the class)

Answer (score 0):

Or

Create a COM wrapper and then reference it from .NET